# How to update mysql row where timestamp field is today?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update a row in a MySql database where a *timestamp* field value is within the current day.

e.g. something like

```
UPDATE records 
   SET firstname="bob" 
 WHERE lastname="jones" 
   AND timer=[today]
```

Comment: today in what sense ..2013-05-26 , Sunday or timestamp???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solutions that cast or modify the field `timer` will never let an index work, that means those queries will be slow. Alike @Stevens answer I would write:

```
UPDATE records 
   SET firstname="bob" 
 WHERE lastname="jones" 
   AND timer >= cast(curdate() as datetime) 
   AND timer < cast(curdate() + interval 1 day as datetime);
```

Then you have the right day at every time.

EDIT: Wrong was

```
   AND timer => cast(curdate() as datetime)
```

corrected was

```
   AND timer >= cast(curdate() as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be your best-performing option (calculating the date range externally and using a BETWEEN).  Casting every row of your table will be significantly slower.

```
UPDATE records SET firstname="bob" 
WHERE lastname="jones" 
    AND timer BETWEEN '2013-05-26' AND '2013-05-27'
```

Comment: Efficient but it will also update rows with `'2013-05-27 00:00:00'`

Comment: yeah sometimes the data imports will bring in the whole day as if it occurred at the stroke of midnite

Comment: @ypercube - Could always use `BETWEEN '2013-05-26' AND '2013-05-26 23:59:59'` - depending on whether that 1 second of precision is required...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use  DATE_SUB(NOW()) in your update.

Here's the help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to a DATE to drop off the time portion and then compare just this.

```
UPDATE records SET firstname="bob" WHERE lastname="jones" AND CAST(timer AS DATE) = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with

```
where date(timer) = date(now())
```

note that will possibly do odd things if you have timezone changes, in which case I'd change everything into epoch, i.e.

```
where unix_timestamp(...pseudo code to get the proper midnight) <= unix_timestamp(timer)
```